# Javascript: Monitor Queue / Continuously Run Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a queue that I push messages to that I'd like to continuously process.

The reason why I need a queue, is because the messages come in too fast for me to finish processing them!

Here's my code:

```
    var messageQueue = [];
    var ws = ...;

//When I get a socket.io message... 
    ws.on('message', function(data)
    {
            //Add it to the queue
            addToQueue(data);
    });

//Function that adds it to the queue:   
    function addToQueue(fullMessage)
    {
        messageQueue.push(fullMessage);
    },

//Function that I'd like to run constantly
    function fetcher() 
    {
        while (messageQueue.length > 0) 
        {
            //get the next message on the queue
            var msg = messageQueue.shift();
            handleMessage(msg);
        }
        //fetcher()?

    }

//Function that works with the message
    function handleMessage(fullMessage)
    {
        //do things with the message
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can get "fetcher" to run anytime there are items in the queue?

Every try I do I end up accidentally calling it recursively and breaking the page :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fetcher() 
    {
        if (messageQueue.length > 0) 
        {
            //get the next message on the queue
            var msg = messageQueue.shift();
            handleMessage(msg);
        }
       setTimeout(fetcher);

    }
```

Comment: This causes recursive problems and I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error :/ I've tried "setTimeout" before, with a 1 second delay, but it did the same :(

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a recursive problem `setTimeout()` is the way to avoid that. There must be something else in your code causing that.

Comment: Because `setTimeout()` adds the function passed to it, to a queue called the event loop  which waits for the callstack to be empty

Comment: Yup! You were right. I was doing setTimeout(fetcher()); instead of setTimeout(fetcher);

Comment: @Kayvar Oh ok I see I was waiting "like is she going to reply" but glad you figured it out. yea you were calling it instead of referencing it. That would work if you were returning another function. But I'm sure you know that

Comment: Haha yeah! Makes sense now. Thanks ^-^

Comment: @Kayvar and also you don't need to put any milliseconds for the second paramter of `setTimeout()` it'll just call it once the call stack is empty

Comment: Thanks! I read up on it and didn't know about that until today!